# How to get the smooth scrolling on tableView? (using swift)

Tags: swift, tableview, smoothing

I am working with tableViews now. Everything works perfect except the smooth scrolling of tableview. Here is a code:

```
CommonFunctions.loadImageAsyncAndVignette(link, imageView: cell.imageViewMiddleSize, article: arrayMainPage[indexPath.row], viewContr: self)
```

This function loads the image asynchronously and format it using CIFilters.

```
 class func loadImageAsyncAndVignette(stringURL: String, imageView: UIImageView, placeholder: UIImage! = nil, article: ArticleInfo, viewContr: UIViewController) {

    imageView.image = placeholder

    let url = NSURL(string: stringURL)
    let requestedURL = NSURLRequest(URL: url!)

    NSURLConnection.sendAsynchronousRequest(requestedURL, queue: NSOperationQueue.mainQueue()) {
        response, data, error in

        if error == nil {

            if data != nil {
                if let image = UIImage(data: data){

                    //imageView.image = UIImage(data: data)

                    let string = stringURL as String
                    article.updateDictionary(stringURL, image: image)

                    let qos = Int(QOS_CLASS_USER_INTERACTIVE.value)

                    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(qos, 0), { () -> Void in

                    let imageEdited = CommonFunctions.vignettePhoto(image, imageViewLocal: imageView)

                           dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
                            imageView.image = imageEdited
                           })
                    })

                }
                else{
                    println("image is nil")
                }
            }
        }else{
            let stringError = error.localizedDescription
            CommonFunctions.showAlert("Ошибка", alertText: stringError, alertButtonText: "Закрыть", viewController: viewContr)
        }
    }
}
```

In the function loadImageAsyncAndVigette, I load the image and format it. Here is formatting function:

```
class func vignettePhoto(inputImage:UIImage, imageViewLocal: UIImageView)->UIImage{


        var beginImage = CIImage(image: inputImage)
        var vignette = CIFilter(name:"CIVignetteEffect")
        vignette.setValue(beginImage, forKey:kCIInputImageKey)

        let centerx = (imageViewLocal.frame.width)/2


        let centery = (imageViewLocal.frame.height)*2
        let center = CIVector(x: centerx, y: centery)

        vignette.setValue(center, forKey:"inputCenter")

        vignette.setValue( 0.5, forKey:"inputIntensity")

        var radius = imageViewLocal.frame.height
        vignette.setValue( radius, forKey:"inputRadius")

        let newImage = UIImage(CIImage: vignette.outputImage)

    return newImage!
}
```

I use function loadImageAsync at

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
 commonFunction.loadImageAsync....
```

}
Everything works. The result is what I wanted. But I dont have smooth scrolling of table view. On simulator, it is hard to scroll at all. On device it is ok to scroll, but anyway i can see that it is a little bit jumping (not smooth). So, can somebody tell me why the scrolling is not smooth? I used async loading but it doesn't help.

Comment: Do you use a reusable cell ?

Comment: hello, i dont get that. What do you mean saying reusable cell. I am pretty sure that the problem is about filtering of image. If I comment filtering part the scrolling goes smooth!

Comment: although you are dispatching to the global queue be aware that this queue has a limited number of threads it can spawn.  I believe that limit is 64. So if you are sharing this queue with other tasks (such as system tasks) and depending on how many images you are converting, you may be filling that queue which, since it's shared, may halt other tasks. It's best to create a queue for your class itself using dispatch_queue_create.  Inside your CommonFunctions class.  That way, you can control your own threads and guarantee your aren't filling up the shared queue.

Comment: Another method you could use in your CommonFunctions is completion or closure blocks which is support in Swift.  This would allow you to dispatch the task in the background and then grab the main queue and update your UI whenever that function finishes doing it's task.

Answer (score 0):

Potential fix for your code

Its unclear exactly why you are inserting so much stuff into your image conversion function since the goal (at least to me) seems to be to convert the image to a stylized photo.  The function IMO would be more clear if it only took in the original image you wanted to convert and returned the converted image.  Instead your function is spawning a network request, then converting the image and also taking in View Controllers as parameters.  With all this juggling around it seems like it could present problems but again my opinion.

In your common functions vignette photo I believe it would be best practice to have this function return as a closure.  If this is a compute intensive task (which based on your question it sounds as such) you should probably treat it like a network request, meaning you should thread it in the background on it's own managed thread or as a closure.

example:

```
CommonFunctions.vignettePhoto(image:UIImage, imageViewLocal:UIImageView, completion:(imageView:UIImage?)->Void) { 
  ... your conversion code ...
  completion(imageView: theConvertedImage)
}
```

One thing I don't understand why you are doing is inserting the UIIMageView as a parameter in this function since you are returning a UIImage and not a UIImageView.  This seems to be redundant but I can't see the full code for your conversion so I cannot determine if it is in fact not a useful parameter.

Then when you go to display the cell example:

No need to spawn a thread since it's in a closure...

```
CommonFunctions.vignettePhoto(image, imageView) { (theConvertedImage)  
  dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ) {
     if let cellToUpdate = tableView.cellForIndex(indexPath) as? YourReusableTableCellClass {
       imageView.image = theConvertedImage 
     }
  }
}
```

But this is just a suggestion.  Try it and see if it works for you.  I've used this method many times in my apps and I get smooth results.  One thing you may also want to do is cache the results of your image conversion.